# VB.NET Serialization and saving

Tags: xml, vb.net, save

I created a form containing some textboxes that needs to be serialized into a XML File in VB.net.

All ok, since the saving part. I could only get a streamwriter / reader to create a single file wich will be replaced everytime someone use the billing app, but i want to save serialized file elsewhere using a Savefile Dialog and i want to open them using openfile dialog, rather than using stream.

Here is the code:

'

```
Public Structure User
    Public UserName As String
    Public PassWord As String
    Public StreetAddress As String
    Public City As String
    Public State As String
    Public Zip As String
End Structure
Private Function CreateRecord() As User
        Dim r As User

        With r
            .UserName = TextBox1.Text
            .PassWord = TextBox2.Text
            .StreetAddress = TextBox3.Text
            .City = TextBox4.Text
            .State = TextBox5.Text
            .Zip = TextBox6.Text
        End With

        Return r

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(User))
        Dim fs As New FileStream("c:\userrecord.txt", FileMode.Create)

        ser.Serialize(fs, CreateRecord())

        fs.Close()


    End Sub
Private Sub LoadIntoTB(ByVal rec As User)

        With rec
            TextBox1.Text = .UserName
            TextBox2.Text = .PassWord
            TextBox3.Text = .StreetAddress
            TextBox4.Text = .City
            TextBox5.Text = .State
            TextBox6.Text = .Zip
        End With


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(User))
        Dim fs As New FileStream("c:\userrecord.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim rec As User

        rec = DirectCast(ser.Deserialize(fs), User)

        LoadIntoTB(rec)
        fs.Close()
    End Sub
```

How to replace FileStream with Save file dialog and openfile dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace the FileStream itself, it is the class which wrties the actual file.  You want to replace the file name variable that is passed in to the constructor.

All the Open (and Save) FileDialog does is effectively sets a string to a file path selected by the user.

All you need to do is declare the class and (set any properties you want on it, such as file type etc) then call .ShowDialog

The documentation can be read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

BTW using code, wiothout attribution, is bad....
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?616479-How-do-I-save-multiple-textboxes-to-a-single-file-and-load-each-one-by-itself&p=4172754#post4172754